# The hypotenuse of a triangle is shortest when the other two legs are equal. Prove this using the Calculus of Variations.

Tags: solution-verification, triangles, calculus-of-variations, triangle-inequality

I started off my proof by of course stating that the different right triangles I would be comparing should have the same area A. I was able to show that what the question is asking is true visually and computationally using the Pythagorean Theorem, and even using the triangle inequality, but I don't really know how to set it up in such a way that I can use the Euler-Lagrange equation in order to prove that this is true.

Equations:

$$\frac{1}{2}xy=A$$

So

$$y(x) = 2A/x \Longrightarrow y'(x) = -\frac{2A}{x^2}$$

Comment: I'd construct a right triangle in a cartesian system, so that $A(0,y)$ and $B(x,0)$ and $C(0,0)$ are the vertices. Since you are analyzing the "equal area situation" the problem should be to minimize the distance between $A$ and $B$ subject to $2S =xy$ (here, the surface area $S$ is an irrelevant constant to calculations, so you can set it to 1)

Comment: What is the exact wording of the problem you've been given?

Comment: @CameronWilliams, "Show that the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle is at its minimum when the length of its other sides are equal to each other using the calculus of variations."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\frac{xy}{2}$ be constant. Then we have $x^2 = (\frac{2A}{y})^2$.

The hypothenus is $h(y)=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{y^2 + \frac{4A^2}{y^2}}$, so $h'(y)=\frac{2y-\frac{8A^2}{y^3}}{2\sqrt{y^2 + \frac{4A^2}{y^2}}}$.

Then $h$ has got a minimum when $h'(y)=0$, so when $2y=\frac{8A^2}{y^3}$, so when $y^4 = 4\cdot \frac{x^2y^2}{4}$, so when $y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\min_{xy=2A}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{\min_{xy=2A}x^2+y^2} $$
and $(x-y)^2\geq 0$ is equivalent to $x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$, with equality attained only at $x=y$. This implies

$$\min_{xy=2A}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{4A}. $$